# How to match and replace string following the match via sed or awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file which I want to modify into a new file using cat. 
So the file contains lines like:

```
name "myName"
place "xyz"
```

and so on....

I want these lines to be changed to

```
name "Jon"
place "paris"
```

I tried to do it like this but its not working:

```
cat originalFile | sed 's/^name\*/name "Jon"/' > tempFile
```

I tried using all sorts of special characters and it did not work. I am unable to recognize the space characters after name and then "myName".

Comment: name "myName" \n      place "xyz"     \n and so on ....

Comment: `sed 's/^name .*/name "Jon"/;s/^place .*/place "paris"/' originalFile > tempFile`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what about this ? `sed -E 's/^(name).*(place).*/\1 "Jon" \2 "Paris"/g' filename`, is it bad thing to do ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein That would not match OP's string.

Comment: Yes i can see this now as it was on the old sample, I might modify it to match the current update, but in general comparing with the one you wrote, is there any difference maybe performance or something ?

Comment: In other orders why you didn't use grouping and then call it with `\1` and `\2` and the second difference i use extended regex but you are not. which makes me wondering is there any major difference that made you prefer to write it this way ? I know you are the expert here with regex :D

Comment: @MostafaHussein Because of the BRE I chose. That's totally preferential: if the part of the pattern you want to keep is a literal you do not need groups/backreferences. KISS approach.

Answer (score 2):

You may match the rest of the line using `.*`, and you may match a space with a space, or `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]`:

```
sed 's/^\(name[[:space:]]\).*/\1"Jon"/;s/^\(place[[:space:]]\).*/\1"paris"/' originalFile > tempFile
```

Note there are two replace commands here joined with s semicolon. The first parts are wrapped with a capturing group that is necessary because the space POSIX character class is not literal and in order to keep it after replacing the `\1` backreference should be used (to insert the text captured with Group 1).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/bzUOKC):

```
s='name "myName"
place "xyz"'
sed 's/^\(name[[:space:]]\).*/\1"Jon"/;s/^\(place[[:space:]]\).*/\1"paris"/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
name "Jon"
place "paris"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. One additional question to it is how do I handle if there are whitespace and tab between name and "myName" . scenarios where I can have only whitespace character after name and scenarios where I have tabs and scenarios where I have both. Currently s/^name.*/name "Jon"/' this works for me. But i want to full proof for above three scenarios.

Comment: @Heyya  You already got your answer : Use `[[:space:]]`, that will work on both `\t` or simple space..

Comment: @Heyya Use `sed 's/^\(name[[:space:]]\).*/\1"Jon"/;s/^\(place[[:space:]]\).*/\1"paris"/' originalFile > tempFile`

Comment: @Heyya Does it work for you? Please consider accepting the answer if it does.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` alternative:

```
awk '$1=="name"{$0="name \"Jon\""} $1=="place"{$0="place \"paris\""} 1' originalFile
```

It will work when there're space(s) before `name` or `place`.
It's not regex match here but just string compare.
`awk` separates fields by space characters which including `\n` or .

Append `> tempFile` to it when the results seems correct to you.